# Determine Multiple Logins in Asp Classic?

Tags: authentication, asp-classic, ip

I been asked to see if we have a problem of people sharing their accounts with their coworkers. The site is in classic asp and I am wondering what would the best way to see if multiple people are logged in at the same time?

I was thinking of recording the ip addresses but if they are all in the same office won't they all of the same ip address then?

I know when you log into google from multiple devices, it will tell you that "2 devices are currently logged in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site runs *outside* of the office, the co-workers will most likely access the site using the same IP-address (the external address of the internet connection of the office). If it's an *internal* (intranet) site, you will most likely see the internal addresses of the co-workers, and you can differentiate them by Ip-address.

If you simply want to differentiate them by browser, just set a cookie with a unique value (like a UUID) when they log in, also store this cookie value on your server (in the database).
Whenever an account is logged in, check if they alread have a cookie, and if the value matches the one in your database.

If they already have a cookie and it matches, then you have the same user (well, actually the same browser) logging in.
If they don't have a cookie, or there's a mismatch, another user (browser) is accessing the account. 
There is one other possibility; if the users clears their cookies, they will also seem to be a 'new' account logging in. But all in all this should be engough to check if the same account is used on multiple devices.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking of doing what you suggested, but instead using LocalStorage instead of cookie storage.  So I think I will go with this solution for now.